# Stop message being redelivered to MDB

Tags: ejb, message, message-driven-bean

Consider the following scenario :

I have a MDB that receives a message. On receiving this message is triggers a series of operations.Some calls are isolated in EJB's that have Requires_New as a transaction attribute and they all succeed. At the very end of the transaction I call sessionContext.setRollbackOnly().

Will this cause the message to be redelivered again to the MDB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what acknowledge mode you use with your mdb session. You can see a full article regarding this topic [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2002/jw-0315-jms.html)